# Accessing multiple databases in Django with using()

Tags: django, django-models

I have been trying since this morning and have read all the posts here and all over about accessing multiple databases in django with no avail. I m looking to access another database on the same server and I have included the databases in the settings.py with aliases. When I m trying to use the using() in the queryset I m getting an error that the Global name 'Objectname' does not exists. I m using postgresql 9.1 with django 1.4

Is there anything that I need to import for this to work? Its not working for me either in the console (python manage.py shell) or the views.

Here is the database setup from settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',     # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'testing',      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'xxxx',                     # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',                 # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': 'localhost',                    # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': 'xxxx',                         # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
},
'app_data': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',     # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'applications',      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'xxxx',                     # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',                 # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': 'localhost',                    # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': 'xxxx',                         # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
},
'ppp_data': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',     # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'platform',      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'xxxx',                     # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',                 # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': 'localhost',                    # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': 'xxxx',                         # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
```

}

Here is the code from the console:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.using('app_data').all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'MyModel' is not defined
```

Here is the error from the view:

```
NameError at /myapp/view
global name 'MyModel' is not defined
```

Please help!

Edited: Just to give a little background I have 3 different apps running on one server with different databases and I wanted to access records across different apps just for viewing. 
The 3 apps are app, ppp and testing and I m trying to access app and ppp data from my testing app.

Comment: Looks like you are missing an import for `MyModel` in your views.

Comment: What would be the syntax to import the `MyModel`from a different database on a different model?

Comment: I have tried doing `from app.MyModel.models import *` on the view in  the testing app but its not working either.

Comment: You aren't importing the model from the database. This problem has nothing to do with the database. This is a pure Python syntax/import problem. I would suggest you read http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: @Mark is correct, this is an import problem. Try `from app.models import MyModel`. If that doesn't work, then you'll need to post your project's layout as we can't guess how you have arranged your files.

Comment: I got it working. I had to add the path to the os path for the app and was able to add it to the view to import the model. Thanks!
@Mark: Do you want to add it as an answer so I could select it?

Comment: An answer from your perspective might be more useful than anything else I could add. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to append the app paths for other apps to the wsgi file.

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/opt/www/test')
sys.path.append('/opt/www/app')
sys.path.append('/opt/www/ppp')
```

Then I could import the models from other apps

```
from pp_app.myapp.models import MyModel
from pp_ppp.myapp.models import MyModel
```

Then this allowed me to use the using() method in the views to get the records:

```
data1 = MyModel.objects.using('app_data').all() 
data2 = MyModel.objects.using('ppp_data').all()
```

Hope this helps someone else.